# Where to start with DB2 and Docusign integration

Tags: api, db2, docusignapi

I'm in the fact finding stage of an integration project to update DocuSign vendor agreements with status flags in our DB2 construction management software.

I'm a SQL developer that was handed this task, and I know nothing about DocuSign schemas or its APIs.

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: read their api docs.  stackoverflow isnt going to do this for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the [DocuSign quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/).

While you may use DB2 for your database, you will still need to run some code on the server in some for of server language like C#, Java etc. You can pick one of 8 languages in the quickstart, see how the APIs work, what data you need and how you may design your system accordingly.